# Parse Data from XML into List with Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, xml-parsing

I am getting data from an XML uploaded on a website. I want to display the text from the XML in a custom `ListView`, which has two `TextView`s. The 'title' should go into the upper `TextView` and the 'guid' into the lower `TextView`. I'm not sure how I should go about doing this. I've written the following Custom Adapter.

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList list;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList list) {
        this.list= list;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.backgroundImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundImage);
            holder.topText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.topText);
            holder.bottomText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottomText);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        DiscourseItem discourseItem = (DiscourseItem) discourseList.get(position);
        holder.topText.setText(discourseItem.getTopText());
        holder.bottomText.setText(discourseItem.getBottomText());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView backgroundImage;
        TextView topText;  //This should display the text in the 'title' field
        TextView bottomText; //This should display the text in the 'guid' field
    }

}
```

I'm currently able to display the two separately in separate `ListView`s with normal `ArrayAdapter`s. Here's the code I've written.

XMLParser.java

```
public class XMLParser extends AsyncTask {

    private URL url;
    public ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> guid = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        try {
            url = new URL(removed);

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), null);

            boolean insideItem = false;

            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                        insideItem = true;
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                        if (insideItem)
                            title.add(xpp.nextText());
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("guid")){
                        if (insideItem)
                            guid.add(xpp.nextText());
                    }
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                    insideItem = false;
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return title;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url){
        try {
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> titles(){
        return title;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> guids(){
        return guid;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        parser = new XMLParser();
        parser.execute();
        title = parser.titles();
        guid = parser.guids();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
            public void run() {
                discourseList = getDiscourseList();
            }
            }, 2000);
        }
        });

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.discourseList);
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, discourseList));
    }

    private ArrayList<DiscourseItem> getDiscourseList() {
        ArrayList<DiscourseItem> listData = new ArrayList<DiscourseItem>();
        String[] topText = new String[title.size()];
        topText = title.toArray(topText);

        String[] bottomText = new String[guid.size()];
        bottomText = guid.toArray(bottomText);

        for (int i = 0; i <= title.size(); i++) {
            try {
                DiscourseItem discourseItem = new DiscourseItem();
                discourseItem.setTopText(topText[i]);
                discourseItem.setBottomText(bottomText[i]);
                listData.add(discourseItem);
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return listData;
    }
}
```

Edit :

I've made the above changes. Now when the parser runs and calls `getDiscourseList()`, it throws the following error at `discourseItem.setTopText(topText[i]);` :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create wrapper class for your upper and bottom values ( something like this, consider another name as I don't know the context of your data):

```
public class TitleGuidPair {
  private final String title;
  private final String guid;
  public TitleGuidPair(String title, String guid) {
    this.title = title;
    this.guid = guid;
  }
 //getters
}
```

And then parse your result to ArrayList of TitleGuidPair. If you want to keep your parsing algorithm you can make some post-processing and build your TitleGuidPairs afterwards from the two lists that you have.

Having that step behind just pass to your adapter List of TitleGuidPairs and in the getView method set top and bottom text like

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.backgroundImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundImage);
        holder.topText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.topText);
        holder.bottomText = (TextView)    convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottomText);
        TitleGuidPair titleGuidPair = list.get(position);  
        holder.topText.setText(titleGuidPair.getTitle());
        holder.bottomText.setText(titleGuidPair.getGuid());
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: So, I've made changes to make use of one `ListView` to show the data, but it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I've updated the OP to reflect the code and the error.

Comment: You declare that the size of your arrays is title.size(). So you can access indexes from 0 to size -1. In your loop, you are flickering through indexes from 0 to size.  Please change your loop from for (int i = 0; i <= title.size(); i++) to  for (int i = 0; i < title.size(); i++). And one more thing, are your arrays, always equal in the number of elements? I mean every title has it's guid? If they differ sometimes, you'll get the same error again as you are assuming they are the same and your loop base only on size one of them. So you should add some validation

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot. Just after I posted this here I went through my code again and noticed this. And yes, there is a guid for every title so that will not be an issue. Thanks a lot!